# Live Generate Skybox from Colours

Tags: 3d, textures

I am writing a program at the moment that creates a 3D environment for a user to navigate. One of the features of it is to have a skybox that changes based on the current time and date. I have written a second program that can determine (for the current time and date) that gives 6 colours, one for each direction, North, East, South, West, Top and Bottom.

What my question is, how can I convert these 6 colours into 6 textures (that are placed on a skybox) with smooth gradients so when they are all together, there are no seams visible?

Comment: Is all you want for the centre of each face to be a specified color and for it to merge with the colors of the neighbouring faces? I can't imagine that producing a nice looking sky.

Comment: @Hannesh Thats exactly what I am looking for. But if you select the correct colours, it does actually look good. I first saw it in a system called ActiveWorlds. If the colours were incorrect, it did look awful, but if they were correct, it created amazing skies